# Bootstrap : Select Image from Modal

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I created a modal in my form which has a bunch of images for the use to select. However i have no idea on how to select the image as in after I click on it , the modal would close and the image name be shown alongside the modal launch button. This is code I have for now:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Click to launch Image Gallery...
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {% for image in images %}
            <input type="image" src="{{ image.url }}" height="100" width="130" style="padding-right: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px;">
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a class for image (just for identification and doing some trick)

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Click to launch Image Gallery...
</button>

<div id='div_img_name'> </div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- images added for example purpose-->

            <input type="image" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/638751551457103872/KN-NzuRl.png" height="100" width="130" style="padding-right: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px;"  class="img">

            <input type="image" src="https://pennyandjohninoz.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/icons-of-australia-3-sydney-opera-house.jpg" height="100" width="130" style="padding-right: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px;"  class="img">                             

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript to add

```
$(".img").click(function(){
    $("#div_img_name").text($(this).attr('src'));
    $('#myModal').modal('hide') ;
})
```

Comment: Works. But the form auto submits after I select the image

Comment: in function after $('#myModal').modal('hide') ; add line  return false; 

accept as answer if this helps !